# Is there a way to make a client realize at a given moment that something on the server has changed other than polling?

Tags: server, client

I have a webapp that needs to notice if a user has been inserted into a table or if inside the table something has changed for that user at any time, so it has to be the server to tell the client that something has changed on the server,
I don't want to use polling because on a large number of people it becomes very heavy on the server, does anyone know of any other alternatives?